# Why while(n) n = n>>1 loop does not terminate with negative n

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu-architecture, bit-shift

My goal was to write a program to count the number of required bits to represent a number in python, in case that i choose `number = -1` or any negative number, the program does not terminate, here is my code :

```
number = -1
cnt = 0
while(number!=0):
    number = number>>1
    cnt+=1
print(cnt)
```

i thought it should print 32 and terminates. it's the same for all negative numbers. i would appreciate if you clarify the reason behind it.

Comment: `number = -1  print(number>>1)  # -1`

Comment: @splash58 i'm looking for the reason that `-1` does not change, i know it will stay the same after each iteration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bit shifting of negative integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549971/bit-shifting-of-negative-integer)

Comment: @organicData nope, it's not, please read the post before suggesting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arithmetic right shift rounds towards -infinity on a normal CPU, or in a language like C.  I assume it's the same in Python.

You're probably thinking about 2's complement integers, where `-1` has all bits set.  A 2's complement signed right shift shifts in a copy of the sign bit, not zero.

`-1 >> 1` = `-1`

---

Python integers are arbitrary-precision so this doesn't make much sense.  The max width is effectively unlimited.

Comment: so it should be the same for all negative numbers

Comment: i presume the problem refers to the sign bit, signed right shift operation doesn't change the sign bit

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi: Yes, exactly.  They just get closer to `-1`, once the sign bit has been copied to all bits.  (Assuming 2's complement).