# arithmetic right shift with sign extension

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am trying to write a function (in C) the does an arithmetic right shift with sign extension.

The result will be held in `R[rd]`.
the source is `R[rs]`
the shift amount is `R[rt]`

In order to simplify my task, I'm trying to write this function in python.

`dest` functions as `R[rd]`
`source` functions as `R[rs]`
`shamt` functions as `shamt`

my try:

```
dest = 0
source = 0xF5042352
print("source = ", hex(source))

shamt = 1
print(f"shifting {shamt}")

sign_bit = source & 0x80000000
shifted = source >> shamt
if(sign_bit):
    mask = (1 << (32 - shamt)) - 1 # create a mask with 1s from the 32 bit to the 32 - shamt bit
    print("mask = ", hex(mask))
    shifted |= (mask << shamt) # sign extend the number

dest = shifted
print("dest =   ", hex(dest))
```

I added some prints just to view the variable contents mid.

The way I went about solving my problem is keeping note on the sign of the number `source`.

if the number was negative before the shift, then I should create a mask with 1's from the rightmost 1 to the 32' bit.

However this doesn't work.
When I shift the number `0xf5042352` by just 1, the resulting dest is:

`0xffffffff`

My algorithm is wrong, I couldn't figure out how to fix my implementation, tips would be appreciated

Comment: Try with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549971/bit-shifting-of-negative-integer)

Comment: The code you show doesn't contain a function definition, but you write that you are trying to write a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
dest = 0
source = 0xF5042352
print("source = ", hex(source))

shamt = 1
print(f"shifting {shamt}")

sign_bit = source & 0x80000000
shifted = source >> shamt
if sign_bit and shamt:
    mask = 0xffffffff << (32 - shamt)
    mask &= 0xffffffff  # only needed in python, to force back to 32 bits
    print("mask =   ", hex(mask))
    shifted |= mask     # sign extend the number

dest = shifted
print("dest =   ", hex(dest))
```

This computes the shifted mask value, which can then be used directly without shifting.  Note that:

1. I added `and shamt` to skip the mask logic if `shamt` is zero.  This is becuase, in C, shifting a 32-bit integer by 32 produces an unspecified result.
2. For the Python version only, the mask value needs to be and-ed with `0xffffffff` to force it back to a 32-bit value.  In C, this won't be necessary with 32-bit integers (but you should use an unsigned integer for the value being shifted).